constrained optimization problem with dominating weight
For a vector $a = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$, define the function:
$$
\varphi(a) = \sum_{i<j} a_i^2 a_j^2 W_{i,j},
$$
where $W_{i,j}$ are predefined (real-valued) weights with $W_{1,n}$ being the largest among them.
Now I want to solve the following optimization problem:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    & \text{maximize} & & \varphi(a) \\
    & \text{subject to} & & \|a\| = 1\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
It seems obvious that $a=(a_1,0,\ldots, 0,a_n)$ is the solution; and if I can show this then I have a proof for what $a_1$ and $a_n$ should be.  I can't quite see how to explicitly show that $a_2=\cdots=a_{n-1}=0$.

How is this in any way convex?

I thought it was, maybe it isn't.  I agree that if we strictly consider the variables $a_j$ then it is not, but I thought it might be convex if we restrict ourselves to say $\tilde{a_j} = a_j^2$.

You didn't specify the norm, so I will assume it is the 2-norm.
Your hypothesis is false, as the following counterexample shows.
Let $W_{1 2} = 2.9, W_{1 3} = 3, W_{2 3} = 2.9$.
The optimal solution (to 4 decimal places) is $a_1 = 0.5807, a_2 = 0.5706, a_3 = 0.5807$ (or the negatives of any or all of these), achieving optimal objective value $= 0.7803$.
If $a_2$ is constrained to $0$, the optimal solution is $a_1 = 0.7071, a_2 = 0, a_3 = 0.7071$ (or the negatives of any or all of these),  achieving optimal objective value $= 0.7500$, which is lower (worse) than when $a_2$ is not constrained to $0$.
This same counterexample (with different optimal values) also works for the infinity norm. I'm not sure about the 1-norm.
